# How to parse date and time dynamically in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

`${__groovy(${__groovy(Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS'\,'2020-12-30 12:29:50.296').getTime(),)},)}` is giving the result 1609268390296. But I need to Pass the value '2020-12-30 12:29:50.29' in above script as dynamic.
I will get modified date for every transaction from DB which I need to pass to above groovy.

```
String ModCount= vars.get("Modified_date_1");
log.info("-----------Count----------"+ModCount);

------------------------------------------------
-----------Count----------2021-01-18 21:43:25.427
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the hard-coded value with the appropriate [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

```
${__groovy(${__groovy(Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS'\, '${Modified_date_1}').getTime(),)},)}
```

or use `vars` shorthand as in your example:

```
${__groovy(${__groovy(Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS'\, vars.get('Modified_date_1')).getTime(),)},)}
```

[image]

Just remember that the [Functions Helper Dialog](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper) doesn't evaluate JMeter Variables as there is no [JMeter Context](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) at this stage, you will have to **run** your test in order to see the function execution result.

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)